# US B1/B2 visa validity

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I was recently approved for a B1 visa.

What is the amount of time typically given with it? All my colleagues got 10 years on theirs. They are telling me that only 10 years are given out as it relates to the B1 visas. Is there any truth to this?

I am in Jamaica, I don't know if my location matters.

Comment: For Vietnamese citizens, it's 1 year.

Comment: There is no **typical** duration. Depending on your profile and the consular officer you can be given anywhere from one even one week to five years or ten years.

Comment: Brazilians receive 10 years.

Comment: Interesting, I recently got mine also. Awaiting to see the amount of years I get. My profile is that of a software developer.

Comment: For Russian passports, it's either 1 year or 2 years.  The first time is no more than 1 year, but often 6 months.  2 years is the absolutely maximum for subsequent visas.

Comment: The default duration of the visa depends on your nationality, not your location. The validity of the visa also is unrelated to the permitted duration of stay in the US.

Comment: What would it be for a Jamaican?  @phoog

Comment: See Oleksandr Kravchuk's answer. Don't forget that each visit will generally be limited to six months, and the US does not look kindly on those who use visa runs to try to use a B visa to reside in the US.  If you spend more than half your time in the US, or even close to that, you can expect at some point to be questioned at length.

Comment: US don't have to worry about that, am only there for a business conference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jamaican citizens may be issues with the B-1 visa valid for up to [120 months](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/fees/reciprocity-by-country/JM.html).

As [Sheik Paul of Osawatomie](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/56513/sheik-paul-of-osawatomie) has written, there is no such a thing as a typical duration of a visa. Visa officer will decide the validity of your visa themselves, so it may be absolutely anything from 24 hours to 10 years.

Comment: My understanding is that the duration of the visa would only be shorter than 120 months if there is some reason for shortening it. I also find it difficult to imagine a reason that would result in issuing a shorter-duration visa rather than just refusing the application altogether.