# US B1/B2 visa validity longer than maximum allowed

Tags: b1-b2-visas, visa-expiration, us-visa

I recently got a US B1/B2 visa with the validity period of 10 years. This is very nice, but since I am a Russian citizen, I was expecting the maximum validity period of 3 years at most.

For example, according to the US travel.gov website the max is 36 months for B-type visas: https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/Visa-Reciprocity-and-Civil-Documents-by-Country/RussianFederation.html. Comments in this post also indicate that the maximum duration is (or used to be) much shorter than 10 years: [US B1/B2 visa validity](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/94131/us-b1-b2-visa-validity)

Is it common to be granted a US visa with a much longer validity period or is it more like an exception? Or maybe the information from travel.gov is not up-to-date, and 10 years is now the official maximum duration for Russian citizens?

Upd: I reside in Canada and since my previous US visa expired less than 4 years ago, I was allowed to send the application documents to the US embassy in Ottawa without interview.

Comment: Which embassy/consulate did you apply for the visa from?

Comment: Do you have another citizenship?

Comment: @jcaron I updated the question with the requested info

Comment: @NicolasFormichella I only have Russian citizenship

Comment: It's possible that, either as an error or as policy, applications in countries other than Russia don't get the limitation which applies to Russian citizens. When you're used to giving 10-year visas all the time, you may forget to notice that you should only give 3 years for this specific application (no idea how much this is automated or manual).

Comment: @jcaron judging from the Foreign Affairs Manual, it's, well, manual.  But there are more countries than just Russia that have B-visa reciprocity periods shorter than 10 years, and they probably issue close to zero B visas to Canadians, since a Canadian citizen can be admitted in B status (and most other nonimmigrant statuses) without a visa.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not an error if you are a permanent resident of Canada.

Travelers who require visas to travel to the US may receive 10 year visas if they are permanent residents of Canada.

> c.  Exception for Canada and The Bahamas:  Permanent residents and
> refugees firmly resettled in Canada and The Bahamas who apply for an NIV
> in their respective countries of residence are subject to the reciprocity
> schedule of that country, not their country of nationality.

See "9 FAM 403.8-3(A)  Applying Reciprocity" at https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM040308.html